# Sorting jQuery dataTables by class name when there is no type or value

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, datatables

I'm using DataTables: https://www.datatables.net/

Heres my HTML:

```
    <div class="dataTable_wrapper">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover center" id="dataTables-example">
           <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th>ID</th>
                  <th>Title</th>
                  <th>Actions</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                   <td>1</td>
                   <td>title 1</td>
                   <td><a href="./action-1"><span class="on"></span></a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                   <td>2</td>
                   <td>title 2</td>
                   <td><a href="./action-2"><span class="off"></span></a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                   <td>3</td>
                   <td>title 3</td>
                   <td><a href="./action-1"><span class="on"></span></a></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
```

I want to sort that table with last column but there's no value to sort... just class "on" and "off". Is there any atrribute that I can add to link tag like rel or something to put there 0/1 values? Or should I do that with JavaScript?

Here's JS code:

```
        $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
            responsive: true,
            "order": []

        });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at dataTables `columns` / `columnDefs` [**`render()`**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) function. You can return various content or values depending on the purpose : `filter`, `display`, `type` or *`sort`*. If you want to sort the column by `0` / `1` based on the `<span>` has the classes `.on` or `.off`, you can do this :

```
var table = $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
    columnDefs : [
        { 
          targets: [2],
          render: function ( data, type, full, meta ) {                  
              if (type == 'sort') {
                  return $(data).find('span').hasClass('on') ? 1 : 0;
              }  else {
                  return data;
              }    
          }   
       }
    ]                                     
});
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/9zvyhgb5/**